# How can enable imap in php.ini

Tags: php, vtiger, php-ini

I was trying to install vtiger in my server for installing vtiger we need to enable imap
I tried to enable imap using php.ini by removing `; from extension=php_imap.dll` but this does not work. Installing page still showing that imap is not enabled. Can i enable this using any php function. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you sure you are altering the correct php.ini? You can check that using phpinfo() as well. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: @AndreschSerj yes i am altering the correct php.ini file because i have changed other things too. It works fine

Comment: Did you restarted the server ?

Comment: For mac users using homebrew look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433648/adding-imap-to-php-7-2-on-osx

Answer (score 16):

On Ubuntu and debian a better way is to enable it this way:

```
sudo apt install php-imap
sudo phpenmod imap
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On CentOS7+

```
sudo yum install php-imap
```

On Ubuntu (<= 14.04) and debian (<= Weezy)

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
sudo php5enmod imap
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **LAMP** server,

First install IMAP using the command on terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-imap
```

Then add this `extension=imap.so` code to your **php.ini** file

Restart your server,

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

It will work

Comment: not the nice way to modify manually some config files which are managed by debian/ubuntu packaging tools or php-tools.

Comment: also forgot, since ubuntu 14.04 you have to restart your services with service apache2 restart

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get purge php5
sudo apt-get install php5=5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4
sudo apt-get install php5-imap php5-curl
```

### add in php.ini

```
extension=imap.so


extension=curl.so
```

reload and restart apache2. clear all your browser history. And Check than.
it may be help.

Answer (score 2):

For PHP7 on LAMP (in Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-imap
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install php-imap``` seems to do a better job

Answer (score 1):

on centos7 php7

```
yum install php-imap
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**
Open This PC and go to this path mentioned below
Yourdrive:\xampp\php(type : configuration Settings)

**Step 2**
Open This file in any editor and find ;extension=imap

**Step 3**
Remove ;(Comment) and save the file and close it.

**Step 4**
Restart Apache and Mysql from your xampp.

**Step 5**
Now you'll able to install Laravel-imap Library
Open cmd (Command Prompt) in your project directory and run this command

**composer require webklex/laravel-imap**