# Adding IMAP to PHP 7.2 on OSX

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, php-imap

I'm using PHP 7.2 on OS X El Capitan, installed using Homebrew (of course). Now I'd like to use some IMAP functions from PHP's IMAP extension, but no matter what I search for, I can't find a way to add the extension on OSX.

Some things I've tried... I have, of course, tried the most commonly recommended approach:

```
$ brew reinstall php --with-imap
```

Yet this fails, returning:

```
Warning: php: this formula has no --with-imap option so it will be ignored!
```

Another method, which I found mentioned in passing, also fails:

```
$ brew install php72-imap

Error: No available formula with the name "php72-imap" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I'm not exactly sure which direction to go in with this. I'm sure there's an easy, probably documented, way of doing this, but I am yet to find it. Perhaps I'm just looking in the wrong places and using the wrong search terms...

Comment: Looks like IMAP extension was removed from Homebrew's PHP https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/25579.

Answer (score 37):

[Kevin Abel](https://github.com/kabel) is providing some of the PHP extensions removed from [Homebrew/core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/). You can install the IMAP extension with:

```
brew tap kabel/php-ext
brew install php-imap
```

To install a specific version, such as 7.2 use:

```
brew install php@7.2-imap
```

Comment: This does not provide IMAP extension for 7.2.

Comment: There is an IMAP extension for PHP 7.1 : https://github.com/kabel/homebrew-php-ext/blob/master/Formula/php%407.1-imap.rb. You can probably adapt it to 7.2 without too much difficulties.

Comment: While this answer give you good general instructions on how to install PHP extensions, it will install the latest PHP version available and NOT the one you need. I went with the answer Alex provided because it's more specific.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how I solved this problem under Mojave:

First, I installed IMAP module for PHP 7.2

```
brew install kabel/php-ext/php@7.2-imap
```

Secondly I copied the imap.so from installed folder to the 'extension_dir' used by php.ini

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/php/20170718/imap.so to /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718
```

Comment: Thank you thank you! This worked for me in PHP 7.4 (just changing the brew install to 7.4 accordingly)

Comment: Thanks! This works for 8.0 as well: brew install kabel/php-ext/php@8.0-imap

Comment: This is the way to go. I'm using packages from the the tap provided by shivammathur but the method remains pretty much the same, just that I had to add the tap for extensions first. Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

There is a much better way to recompile php with IMAP extension directly using Homebrew.

UPDATE 2023/09: this procedure works even with the php8. Just use *php* instead of versioned formula *php@7.4*. Please note openssl has changed version to *openssl@3*.

1. Run **brew edit php@7.4**
2. Add **depends_on "imap-uw"** at the end of the depends_on section
3. Check which version of **openssl** is in the depends_on section
4. Add **--with-imap=#{Formula["imap-uw"].opt_prefix}** at the end of the --with section
5. Add **--with-imap-ssl=#{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_prefix}** after --with-imap. Check sure it is the same version as in the depends_on section
6. Run **HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew reinstall --build-from-source php@7.4**
   UPDATE 2023/02: If you dont prepend with HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1, then modified file is not used. Behavior changed from 2023/01, more on https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/14412
7. It is not necessary to enable the php_imap.so extension in php.ini, because it is already compiled into PHP. You can check phpinfo();

In case of a formula update in the feature, just edit the formula again and reinstall with --build-from-source.

Comment: This is a good answer because it does not depend upon random taps. It worked for me.

Comment: It worked! These are the kind of answers I love to see: clear, step by step, and working.

Answer (score 14):

After expired `kabel/php-ext/php@7.2-imap`, I used another tap:

```
brew tap shivammathur/php

brew tap shivammathur/extensions

brew install imap@7.2
```

Comment: this is only solution that worked for me on mojave and php 7.3

Comment: Big Sur and php@7.4 here, and also this solution worked!

Comment: Still best answer. For higher php versions use the correct version constant like imap@8.1 or imap@8.2
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This answer for those who prefer installing `imap` ext using native commands without adding other taps or smth else.

In short we need to compile extension from sources.
Ok, here is the process.

```
$ # Download sources from php.net of already installed php version. 
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.3.5.tar.gz
$ gunzip php-7.3.5.tar.gz
$ tar xvf php-7.3.5.tar
$ # Go to ext dir 
$ cd php-7.3.5/ext/imap
$ # prepare extension using phpize command, you should 
$ # ensure that you use phpize of proper version from 
$ # already installed php version as checking the API version for example
$ phpize
$ # prepare dependencies
$ # install openssl and imap
$ brew install openssl
$ brew install imap-uw
$ # after all installation check the installed paths of the exts
$ ./configure --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2r/ --with-imap=/usr/local/Cellar/imap-uw/2007f/
$ make
$ # get extension dir 
$ php -i | grep extension_dir
extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731 => /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731
$ cp modules/imap.so /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/
$ # add extension to your php.ini
# [imap]
# extension="imap.so"
```

That's it. Be lucky!

Comment: Life saver. This should be the accepted answer. And while executing the commands anyone should check the proper php, openssl, imap-uw version and folders in their local.....

Comment: This is for linux rigth ?.. any clue for Mac OS X ?

Comment: Truly a life saver! Thanks @wtorsi! Works on my MacOS Big Sur in 2021 with php 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have trouble in Mojave, I have forked the repository and fixed it use: 
`brew tap vishal-sancheti/php-ext` instead

Comment: unfortunately it does not work - Error: Cannot tap vishal-sancheti/php-ext: invalid syntax in tap!