# PHP Imap , php 7.4.3 on mac osx catalina

Tags: php, imap

This is officially driving me nuts! I'm trying to work with a laravel package for imap functions and I've installed everything there but I get a missing class error for imap_open

I know this means the imap module is not installed, or is problematic, at the php level.

I've edited my php.ini file to have `extension=imap` and now when I run any php command from the terminal CLI I get `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0`

When I navigate to user/local/lib/php I have a 7.4 folder, in that I have a conf.d folder, pear.conf file, php-fpm.consf file, php-fpm.d folder, and php.ini file

What do I need to do at this point?

Comment: Have You tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433648/adding-imap-to-php-7-2-on-osx

Comment: @num8er yes I did, and I was able to move the imap.so file into the local folders and uncomment the file in the php.ini file. Still while in the directory for this project typing ```php -m``` doesn't show imap

Comment: seems `php -v` will show that it’s different than 7.4

Comment: @num8er ok if I run php-v it shows version 7.3.9 but before that I get a startup error loading dynamic library 'imap' with ```code signature in (/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so) not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.)) in Unknown on line 0```

Comment: imap.so which You're talking about I don't know for which version of php is. but I recommend to remove it from pecl folder (and remove from configs if it's appearing again). then simply do steps in my answer below, I've done it locally and it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've upgraded my `7.3` to `7.4` and added `imap` extension which does not exist in pecl.

So steps are:

1) `brew update`

2) `brew upgrade php`

3) `sudo rm /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so`

4) `brew tap kabel/php-ext`

5) `brew install php-imap`

6) `php -m | grep imap`

Comment: OK I went through these steps exactly and the. last step gave me ```PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so))```

Comment: then when I immediately run php-v in the command line I get 7.3.9

Comment: @TomN. as I said in comments above if it will be appearing again remove that imap.so from config (php.ini), since `brew install php-imap` installs it to different place

Comment: I did the sudo rm step in your answer, but when I run php --ini in the command line it still shows the config file it's using is at /etc/php.ini

Comment: OK I removed extension=imap from that file and now php -m | grep imap returns nothing

Comment: cause You're using php 7.3.9

Comment: close terminal and open new one

Comment: run: `brew upgrade php` and after `php -v`

Comment: ok yes it does say php 7.4.3 now. so now the grep command gives ```PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209386/discussion-between-num8er-and-tom-n).

Comment: After doing only (4) and (5) everything was upgraded anyway. So the result is a brand new PHP 8 installation (I had 7.4)

Comment: Thank you. I'm using shivammatur on my big sur. tapping the shivammatur extensions didn't solve my problem but your answer did

Answer (score 6):

It is a time to update the package. We need php@7.4-imap (actually its an alias to php-imap that loads php-8.0.0 source code.

Answer (score 6):

I've tries all of the things. But, nothing works. Finally, I got Shivammathur git brew extensions -

**Homebrew tap for PHP extensions** - https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions

**Process to install imap extension for php `7.4` -**

**Get PHP 7.4 & Extensions:**

```rb
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew link --force --overwrite php@7.4
brew tap shivammathur/extensions
```

**Get Any extension now, like imap**

```rb
brew install imap@7.4
```

After then, I can perfectly enabled `php-imap` on my machine. Hope, it will help somebody.

Answer (score -1):

I would check to see if Step 1 is actually required, otherwise this worked for me on Mac OS 10 Catalina 10.15.1

```
brew install php@7.4-imap (not sure if required)
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew services restart php
brew install imap@7.4
brew tap shivammathur/extensions\n
brew install imap@7.4\n
php -m | grep imap
```