# PHP Imap issue on php 7.4.3 on mac osx catalina

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, composer-php

[image]

I've edited my php.ini file to have extension=imap and now when I run any php command from the terminal CLI I get

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

I have these in my php.ini

```
extension_dir=/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902

Additional .ini files parsed=/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini, /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/imap.ini

Protocols=dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, gophers, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, mqtt, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp

IMAP c-Client Version=2007f

SSL Support=enabled

Kerberos Support=enabled
```

What do I need to do at this point?

Comment: does `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/imap` exist?

Comment: No. @apokryfos. It does not exist there.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imap.installation.php though if you are using homebrew to install and manage PHP there may be a package you can get from there. Also imap does not seem to be a pecl extension so also check if the commands just work before trying to install it

Comment: @apokryfos I used this one to install imap. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591870/php-imap-php-7-4-3-on-mac-osx-catalina

Comment: If you install it with homebrew you should not need to modify your php.ini , it should do that for you. Have you actually checked if the extension works before modifying your php.ini but after you installed it using homebrew?

Comment: @apokryfos I can found 20190902 at this path: /usr/local/lib/php/20190902 instead of pecl and there are 2 files are existed in that folder named opcache.a and opcache.so

Comment: It's not working before I added extension so first I did uncomment imap from php.ini after that I installed imap through homebrew and then did comment of php.ini's extension now error is gone. Thanks! @apokryfos

Comment: if you have installed it using homebrew, then you should comment imap extension in .ini file