# Call to undefined function imap_open()

Tags: php, homebrew, imap

I'm trying to IMAP working on my Mac running Big Sur.

I used HomeBrew to install PHP 8.1:

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew tap shivammathur/extensions
brew install imap@8.1
```

PHP is working and according to the phpinfo() it's using the correct path.
There's also the additional path to the imap.ini
The path in the imap.ini exists and there is a imap.so

When i run "php -m" imap is mentioned in the list.

But when I run my code I get the error:

```
Call to undefined function imap_open()
```

I tried reinstalling the php with extensions and I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/66047249/909723 but no success

Hope someone can help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap\_open() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654453/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imap-open-in-php)

Comment: No, I'm not using XAMP/MAMP

Comment: @Peter what are you using to execute PHP requests?

Comment: @IanBrindley I don't understand what you're asking but i'm using a local webserver running apache

Comment: @Peter Apache :) Have you restarted the Apache?

Comment: @IanBrindley Multiple times

Comment: @Peter can you verify that your Apache web server is using the same PHP that you have installed with brew? To verify this put `phpinfo();` in your `index.php` or other script and run it through Apache and web browser to verify... It is not uncommon that Apache is using a system installed PHP -  as a last step after brew installation of php there are instructions how to configure your Apache to use the brew managed PHP.

Comment: @PlamenNikolov it's running the only version (8.1.3) of PHP, I even compiled PHP with IMAP and IMAP is still not showing up in the phpinfo();

Comment: @Peter If you are using the system Apache, try using the brew package `httpd`.